# How to obtain a hex number from an array of 1s and 0s in C?

Tags: c, arrays, binary, char, hex

I am creating a program that takes a decimal number, makes it IEEE-754 single precision format, then from the sign-bit, expononent-bits, and mantissa-bits it creates an hex number of length 8. I am unable to transform an int array I made consisting of the all the bits needed into hex.

I have tried a piece of code and it works however it does print the result backward and I am unsure how to flip it. I have also tried to store in an array but when I print that array out I get boxes.

```
void printHexChar(unsigned char value){
    unsigned char lower = value & 0xf; // Use binary 'and' to mask the lower byte
    unsigned char upper = (value & 0xf0) >> 4; // Use binary 'and' to mask upper byte

 if(upper >= 10) // Same as lower
        upper = 'a' + (upper - 10);
    else
        upper = upper + '0';
    if(lower >= 10) // If lower is in range [10-15], than add a value [0-5] on 'a'.
        lower = 'a' + (lower - 10);
    else
        lower = lower + '0'; // It's in range [0-9], so we have to add it to '0'.






    printf("%c%c",lower,upper); // Print out the hexadecimal number
}
```

```
void bin_array_to_hex(int *b, int length){
    if(length % 8){
        printf("Must be dividable by eight!\n");
        return;
    }
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int j;
    for(i = 0; i < length; i = j){
        unsigned char a = 0; // Has length of 8 bits
        for(j = i; j < i+8; ++j){ // take 8 bits...
            a |= b[j]<<(j-i); // and set them in a

        }
       printHexChar(a);
    }           
}
```

```
bin_array_to_hex(arrayhex2, 32);
```

I expect the input of 2.5 to be 40200000 but it is 00000204. The array depends on the inputed float number but for 2.5 it is 01000000001000000000000000000000.

Comment: Store the result in array of char and then flip the array. That should be easy enough.

Comment: Hello, Little endian?

Comment: Please provide a [example]. At least show us your `int` array.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I have tried that, it doesn't print any numbers just boxes.

Comment: @AlexisFlanigan you should show is your failing code, otherwise we can't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that we have all bits together, I can show you a solution. I wont explain the boiler plate code around the relevant part, though.

Since your array has all the bits in sequence you can just shift them one after the other into your destination variable. I have called it `value`. It has to be initialized just in case that not all bits are given.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int array[] = {
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
};

void bin_array_to_hex(int *b, int length) {
    if (length % 8) {
        printf("Length must be dividable by eight!\n");
        return;
    }
    unsigned int value = 0;
    if (length / 8 > sizeof value) {
        printf("Length must be <= %u!\n", 8 * (unsigned int)sizeof value);
        return;
    }
    while (length--) {
        value <<= 1;
        if (*b) {
            value |= 1;
        }
        b++;
    }
    printf("%08x\n", value);
}

int main(void) {
    bin_array_to_hex(array, sizeof array / sizeof array[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Some more notes:

- There is no need for additional local variables. The parameters can be seen as local variables, actually they are handled quite similar in common environments. So we can use them (here: `b` and `length`) directly.
- You don't need a self made hex printer. `printf()` can do this for you. If you need the result in a string, use `sprintf()`.